# What triggers Google Translate popup?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, localization

Web page has a head element with English language set:

```
<head lang="en">
```

My computer has English language set as well, but when I navigate to the page (with Chrome), I get a Google Translate popup offering me translation to Portuguese. I'm not Portuguese, nor did I visit any Portuguese websites that could have left any cookies that could cause this.

Why is this happening? What else could trigger the wrong language popup?

Comment: did you check your IP address ? are you using VPN ?

Comment: I am using VPN, but still, no connection to Portugal.

Comment: ok then go to Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Languages > check the default language

Comment: UK English and US English :)

Comment: so check something else, make a sure there is no cookie in your browser from google, sometimes it happens